# set flag who have count greater than a specified number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table to store notification and each user need to see latest 5 notification and need to soft delete remaining notifications(as per the request from client).

In the attached image I need to set IsDeleted flag to 1 for each user who have more than 5 notifications(need to sort in descending order of ID and set flag who have count greater than 5)[image]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
with toupdate as (
      select n.*,
             row_number() over (partition by username order by id desc) as seqnum
      from notifications n
     )
update toupdate
    set isdeleted = 1
    where seqnum > 5;
```